# Is CVE2012-5373 fixed in OpenJDK7?

Tags: java, cve

Can anyone please tell me if CVE2012-5373 is fixed in OpenJDK7? I have searched for the fix details, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you're using OpenJDK7?  The most recent version is 11....

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Indeed versions prior to 11 aren't publicly updated (or however they phrase it). They're going to have a lot worse known than a `HashMap` implementation (that was not originally meant to be hardened against DoS) susceptible to a DoS.

Answer (score 1):

This CVE is not fixed in OpenJDK7. Both Debian and redhat report it as unfixed:

- https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2012-5373: unfixed
- https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2012-5373: Will not fix